# Is it possible to create a list of multiple objects, where the objects take multiple arguments?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, collections, jvm

### Simplified example

Imagine I define a person as:

```
public class Person (String name, int age)
```

and then I have a list of people...

```
public class ListOfPeople {
     private ArrayList<Person> people;
}
```

then I want to be able to create a few people in one go, do something like...

```
ListOfPeople myFriends = new ListOfPeople("Chris",33,"Adam",26,"John",50)
```

I know I could initialise each one individually and then add them, I was just curious to see if I could make some way to just create them 'on the fly' in the way above

Comment: What is the source for the set of names and ages?

Comment: Is there something wrong with doing `new ListOfPeople(new Person("Chris", 33), new Person("Adam", 26), new Person("John", 50))`?  Then you aren't adding them after you create them and it's still kind of on the fly.  If that doesn't work you could always create a custom `ArrayList` class for yourself that inherits the basic `ArrayList` and has an custom constructor that takes in strings and initializes everything so you could pass in the data like in your example.

Comment: You could also take some inspiration from java 9+'s `java.util.Map.of(K, V, K, V, ...)`

Comment: Just for the record: List of people, you solve by creating a simple `List<People>` object. If your class **solely** holds that internal list ...then it doesn't add any value to your design. Java has collections already. Your new class **only** makes things harder, for example you would have to implement equals(), hashCode(), and toString() in order to do something useful. So, imho, the first thing to do: ask yourself if you really need or want that special ListOfSomething class. Or, the other way round: do you think you want to create such a new class for each and any

Comment: new "data" class you need? ListOfPets, ListOfResponses, ListOfFoos, ListOfBars?!

Comment: @GhostCat in real life the scenario is more complex and requires more than just a simple list, I was just stripping it down for brevity and ease of understanding

Comment: @MichaelPlatt nothing wrong with that, just always looking for other ways :)

Comment: I've googled for "aggregate initialization" in Java and found nothing.

Comment: Related [curly brackets in C++ and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643245/curly-bracket-initialization-in-c-and-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Person> personListConstructor(String... data) {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length / 2; i++) {
        personList.add(new Person(data[2 * i], Integer.parseInt(data[2 * i + 1])));
    }
    return personList;
}
```

Of course it lacks validation - there must be an even number of arguments, every second must be an integer. Other solution would be to use array of `Object`s:

```
List<Person> personListConstructor(Object... data) {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length / 2; i++) {
        personList.add(new Person((String) data[2 * i], (Integer) data[2 * i + 1]));
    }
    return personList;
}
```

Same notices here.

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant but it certainly works for my requirement!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a constructor that accepts an array of `Person` objects:

```
public class ListOfPeople {
     private ArrayList<Person> people;

     public ListOfPeople(Person... persons) {
          for (Person person : persons) {
               people.add(person);
          }
     }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
ListOfPeople myFriends = new ListOfPeople(new Person("Chris", 33), new Person("Adam",26), new Person("John",50));
```

Answer (score 3):

Was wondering how to do it using lambda, and here is simple solution, if anyone is interested.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(List<String> attributes) {
        attributes.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(this::setName);
        attributes.stream().skip(1).findFirst().map(Integer::parseInt).ifPresent(this::setAge);
    }
    // getters, setters

}

public class ListOfPersons {
    List<Person> people;

    public ListOfPersons(String ...persons) {
        final int chunkSize = 2;
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        this.people = Stream.of(persons)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(Person::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.people.toArray()));
    }
}
```

So new `new ListOfPersons("A", "1", "B", "2", "C")` returns

```
[Person{name='A', age=1}, Person{name='B', age=2}, Person{name='C', age=0}]
```

Comment: I will have to take some time to read and understand how this is working, but this looks very impressive! I am not familiar with streams and have no idea what an AtomicInteger is, but I will do some research :)